# C++ adding "self" to a map during constructor

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and a bit stumped. I'm trying to add data to a `std::map` on initialization of a class, but the catch is I'm trying to add the instance of the class being created.

Example:

```
namespace Test
{

    inline std::map<std::string, Doodad> testMap;

    class Doodad
    {
        public:
            Doodad(std::string test)
            {
                testMap["qwe"] = this;
            }
    };

}
```

Now this ovciously won't work, because `Doodad` isn't defined, so I tred something a little more hacky (and probably a terrible, terrible idea, but I'm just playing with it and learning how things work).

```
namespace Test
{

    class Hack
    {
    public: 
        Hack() {};
    };

    inline std::map<std::string, Hack> testMap;

    class Doodad: public Hack
    {
        public:
            Doodad(std::string test) : Hack()
            {
                testMap["qwe"] = this;
            }
    };

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It doesn't work because `this` is a `Doodad*`, not a `Doodad`.

Comment: And you didn't forward declare `Doodad` so it doesn't name a type at that point

Comment: `testMap` contains whole `Hack`s or `Doodad`s (depending on which example you want to refer to). They are not pointer or references to the one being constructed, they are entirely different. This solution looks like it may be influenced by Java, C# or another other similar language where an object variable is a reference to an instance that can be shared with other object variables. This is not how it works in C++. You will need to some form of pointer or reference type if you want something to refer to something that exists elsewhere.

Comment: It's better to add the object after it has been created. Adding it during construction doesn't make sense

Comment: @Artyer what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the class first, then declare the variable, then define the function:

```
class Doodad
{
    public:
        Doodad(std::string);
};

inline std::map<std::string, Doodad> testMap;

Doodad::Doodad(std::string) {
    testMap.emplace("qwe", *this);
}
```

P.S. `this` is a pointer, so you cannot add that to the map whose values are not pointers. Furthermore, you cannot use `operator[]` of the map, since `Doodad` is not default constructible.

Comment: clearly the map have to memorize a pointer to (or equivalent), else lot of problems ...

Comment: @bruno Frankly, storing pointers into the map has more potential for problems. Whether one or the other is appropriate depends on what OP intends to do with the map.

Comment: yes by definition if I can say, anyway we are not everywhere but in a constructor, and we can easily suppose the destructor will remove from the map.

Comment: BTW why the _inline_ ? g++ itself doesn't like _inline variable_

Comment: @bruno ask OP, as they chose to use it :) I suppose it is for purposes of keeping the example minimal and complete, while still valid as to be included in a header. (My answer is no longer valid as a header, as I didn't use inline for the constructor). `g++ itself doesn't like inline variable` is your g++ old perhaps? It is a C++17 feature. I don't have a strong opinion on whether one should use `inline` or `extern` static variables. Static variables should often be avoided in general.

Comment: I'm only on my third day of C++ so if I'm using non-standard practices I apologize. I'm just learning, coming from a JavaScript background. Resharper tells me that declarations in header files should have the `inline` keyword. That's why I use it.